# Split jupyter notebook into several files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am currently creating many tables in python and most of the cells need their own SQL query. I am ending up with a long list of SQL querys. Ideally I would put the table creation of each table in its own file and load the files from a main notebook.

Is there a way to run sub-notebooks (containing the tables) from one main notebook? Mathematica has the `EvaulateNotebook[]` function which does exactly this. For python I found the `nbconvert` package which seems to come close to what I need. However, `nbconvert` seems to run in its own kernel. I would need the sub-notebook to have access to all variables in the main-notebook and subesquently the main-notebook to have acess to the variables in the sub-notebook.

In the end I would like to have the convenience of the notebooks in terms of editing, while not having to scroll through each and every table if I only need to change one table. So I am a bit reluctant to build a standard python package which I import, but would rather have a way to run a sub-ipynb in a way as if the cells where in the main-notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is currently possible in Jupyter to have "child" notebooks in the same way you can with knitr.

Fernando Perez wrote a [script to merge together multiple notebooks](https://gist.github.com/fperez/e2bbc0a208e82e450f69) which may be helpful in your case to avoid having to scroll through a lot of text.

It looks like this may also eventually be incorporated into the main [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) codebase (see issue [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/253)).